# Quickly see the effect of a setting in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom

I use the "Before Only" option all the time to quickly compare my current edits and the original photo.

I would like to know if there is a way to toggle a single setting (like Exposure, or Contrast, or Clarity) to see my photo without this setting. This would be particularly useful after applying a preset, to see the effect of a single edit on the overall look (similar to "Before Only" or the on/off toggle on Tone Curves, Colors, etc.).

I tried with option/cmd/shift and other modifiers, but I don't know if it's possible at all.

Cheers.

Edit: I obviously know that I can undo/redo. I want to know if there's a quicker built-in way like a shortcut to toggle a single setting. ;)

Comment: CTRL+Z to undo it, and same again to re-do it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the undo/redo commands under the Edit menu would do what you are looking for here- after applying an edit or preset, undo would remove the last adjustment and a subsequent redo would re-apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the quickest -and always working- way to do this is just applying the change and then use `undo` or `redo` commands to toggle a before/after view. To do it quickly you can use the appropriate keyboard shortcuts (i.e. `Ctrl-Z` on Windows and `Cmd-Z` on MacOS).

I'm not sure if it was possible in previous versions of Lightroom, but on Lightroom Classic CC 7.3.1 you can hover on a preset (without any click) and see how it will look if applied (I remember that in older versions you could see the preview only on the top left preview box).

So you could create a set of presets for each single setting, such as -2 EV to -2 EV or -20 clarity to + 40 clarity, and then just hover each preset to see how it would be like if applied. As you hover the cursor outside of the preset sidebar, you'll see your current settings.

See the [video in this page](https://www.proloststore.com/products/graduated) to better understand what I mean.

They are selling a set of such presets, but if you have the time and the patience to setup them for yourself, at least for the settings you care most about, you don't need to buy them to get this workflow in Lightroom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm already doing a reset (double click on the label of the setting), then undo/redo to compare.

I hoped there was a quicker way, but alas, that's not the case. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to reset it and then cmd-z to see the changes. Just do this right from making the changes. Very subtle difference but it means when you continue if happy with the changes u are not continuing for what was the ‘undo of your reset’

Just getting rid of a stage, but can add up if doing this a lot. I find you can have your left hand poised to undo and make changes with the mouse and see a before after view by undoing very quickly.